# websql error on phonegap/cordova

Tags: cordova

I am trying to insert data into websql. I am testing on Chrome and it is not working. I'm getting `error processing: SQL undefined`.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "News", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

//create table and insert some record
function populateDB(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT NOT NULL, description TEXT NOT NULL,link TEXT NOT NULL,category INT)');

    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO news (title,descriptionlink,category) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',["test1","descrip","link2",2]);
}


// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(tx, err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}});
```

Answer (score 4):

With PhoneGap and Cordova, you should use deviceready event to do your stuffs. And not in "document ready" event.

Make sure you have included cordova.js file before these code.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
   var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "News", 200000);
   db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

//create table and insert some record
function populateDB(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS news (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT NOT NULL, description TEXT NOT NULL,link TEXT NOT NULL,categorie INT)');

    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO news (title,descriptionlink,categorie) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',["test1","descrip","link2",2]);
}


// Transaction error callback
function errorCB(tx, err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}});
```

For more information on this event, refer to http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready